# I want to make my search button search my website in html =)

Tags: html

How do I actually make my search button look around my website for a specific page? Here is my website code at the moment:

```
<center><in <center><img src= file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/aminisgay/lol/googlelogo1997.jpg alt="lol" width="351" height="113"></center> <center><input name="q" type="search" title="Search" placeholder="Search" autofocus="" required=""></center>

<form action="file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/aminisgay/lol/SearchResults.html" name=f>

<title> Website </title>

<center><input type="submit" title="Search" value="Search" accesskey="s"></center>


<center><h1> <a href="file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/aminisgay/lol/About.html">About</a><h1></center>

<center><h2><font color="red">Subscribe for updates!</font></h2></center>

<center><p>© SuperboySR | 2013<p></center>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="SimpleCSS.css"
```

I'm not sure if all the code is needed.

Comment: Are you asking how to implement a search engine for the pages in your site?

Comment: Yes, something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way would be to use [Google Custom Search](https://www.google.com/cse/).  This allows you to point Google Search at your specific website.

This does not require any special server-side code for your website.  But it does mean that you are dependent on Google to index your page before changes are picked up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search your website(static /dynamic). You need to use DTSearch on all the file you have in server. Once word hit matches any file the you need to return URL for perticuler page.

Hope this help you. Please provide more information for specific solution.

Thanks ,

Roshan

Comment: how do i use DT search?